# Evernote SDK: Cannot upload a note into my Sandbox account

Tags: ios, objective-c, evernote

I followed Evernote github tutorial "https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Getting_Started.md" to upload a note from my iOS application into evernote. After running and building, I am unable to create note in my sandbox account.

```
//AppDelegate.m
#import <ENSDK/ENSDK.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Initial development is done on the sandbox service
// When you want to connect to production, just pass "nil" for "optionalHost"
NSString *SANDBOX_HOST = ENSessionHostSandbox;

// Fill in the consumer key and secret with the values that you received from Evernote
// To get an API key, visit http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/
NSString *CONSUMER_KEY = @"my_consumerkey";
NSString *CONSUMER_SECRET = @"my_consumer_secret";

[ENSession setSharedSessionConsumerKey:CONSUMER_KEY
                        consumerSecret:CONSUMER_SECRET
                          optionalHost:SANDBOX_HOST];
}

//My EditTextController
#import "EditTextController.h"
#import <ENSDK/ENSDK.h>
@implementation EditTextController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self.textEditor setText:self.textstring];
_textEditor.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:24];
_textEditor.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

//Initializing and creating ENNote and assigning a note content
ENNote * note = [[ENNote alloc] init];
note.content = [ENNoteContent noteContentWithString:self.textstring];
note.title = @"My First Note";
[[ENSession sharedSession] uploadNote:note notebook:nil completion:^(ENNoteRef * noteRef, NSError * uploadNoteError) {
      if (uploadNoteError==nil) {
        NSLog(@"Upload successful");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Error%@",uploadNoteError);
}];
}
```

//The error is Domain=ENErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not appear to be actually authenticating any user here. Before calling the `-uploadNote:..` method, you'll need to authenticate a user so that the SDK successfully connects to a particular user's account when making calls to the service.

[Details are here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Getting_Started.md#authenticate) in the Getting Started document on Github, but essentially you'll need a place in your UI to have some sort of "connect to Evernote" button and invoke the `-authenticateWithViewController...` method etc from there.

(If you're just hacking around to test it out, try throwing it in your `-viewDidLoad` (or `-viewDidAppear`) method and call the upload note stuff in its completion block.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and assume the error codes correspond to the `ENErrorCode` enum defined here:

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/evernote-sdk-ios/ENSDK/ENError.h#L36

"2" would be the highlight part, i.e., `ENErrorCodeAuthExpired`, which would suggest there's something wrong with your auth credentials.

Comment: No problem with credentials. I just generated new API key and repeated the same process.

Comment: What does calling `isAuthenticated` on your `ENSession` instance yield? Looks like [this is the check](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/evernote-sdk-ios/ENSDK/ENSession.m#L852) that throws the `ENErrorCodeAuthExpired` error.

Comment: The error is not at isAuthenticated. I put break points and checked. This means it is authenticating.

Comment: The file, you pointed out is not called in my code. Strange. ENSession.m

Comment: And if you call it manually, and log the result, is it true or false?

Comment: Is it related to "CFBundleURLTypes" in info.plist main file?

Comment: One more point to note. I am using iOS9 and in iOS9, you cannot find "libxml2.dylib" this lib. After deep search, I came to know the this lib is now in libz.tdb in iOS9. So, I added libz.tdb.

Comment: Well, if `isAuthenticated` is false, then you do have an authentication problem. If you took the code straight of the tutorial, then maybe you can open an issue on their GitHub, so that sb with better understanding of the SDK works can take a look.

Comment: Yes, I took it straight from GitHub. There are only few steps but still facing this issue. I opened the issue on Github also. https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/issues/114